# How to use datepart in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, criteria

In my project i display the pending status in week manner.i wrote a below sql query for that

```
SELECT count(Distinct(DATEPART(wk,spentDate))) FROM [tblTimesheet] where TimesheetStatus = 'Pending' and Approver = 6
```

How to write the equivalent criteria or hql for the above query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: DATEPART (I'm guessing) is a SQL-SERVER specific command. If you have some form of Date object be it a `java.util.Date` or some form of `JodaTime` date object, you would need to parse out/calculate the data you need and pass that part of your criteria. There is no native Hibernate function to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
[How to query on a month for a date with Hibernate criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418524/how-to-query-on-a-month-for-a-date-with-hibernate-criteria), was useful for me!

Maybe you need http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html to understand how to use the equivalents of MSSQL DATEPART in MySQL

Comment: Thanks Richards,It gives me a  lot of help to fix the above issue