# Get current month Criteria in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am transforming my jdbc connections to Hibernate Criteria and I have this query:

```
select sum(tran_amt) from   mytable where tran_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm');
```

The where criteria part is the place am stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query on a month for a date with Hibernate criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418524/how-to-query-on-a-month-for-a-date-with-hibernate-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Define date as java variable, and compare it to the criteria value. E.g., depending on criteria version of course:

```
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.ge(from.get("trainDate"), new Date());
```