# Select all records from MySql database based on month

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sqldatetime

I would like to get all records from a MySQL date field with the Hibernate Criteria API. Basically I would like the query to select all rows from the date to a predefined month (e.g January). This is my MySql query that executes successfully

```
select * from user u where month(u.birth_date) = 1; //1 for January
```

I want to convert this  MySql Query to hibernate Criteria, like

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("month(birth_date)", month));
```

but it's give error.

DB DataType for birth_date is Timestamp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418524/how-to-query-on-a-month-for-a-date-with-hibernate-criteria) work for you?

Comment: The query is running, but I want it in the Hibernate Criteria format.

Comment: That's what the answer to that question gives. Custom Criterion class

Comment: I want to use Criteria.add(Restrictions.eq( some_input ) format, how to make work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own expression. Then use that expression with criteria. You can see this link on how to create expression.
[How to query on a month for a date with Hibernate criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418524/how-to-query-on-a-month-for-a-date-with-hibernate-criteria)